# Python - parse gzip json with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a gzip json file and I want to parse it in parallel using multiprocessing.

How can I open the gzip file, and for each process within the multiprocessing library, I would read a line from it and parse as I want to.

In other words, I would have a gzip file opened (imagine it as a queue) and 4 process that would consume these lines and parse it.
So if I have 1000000 json lines in this file, each process would consume aproximate 250000 lines.

The file contains JSON strings, one per line. Like this:

{"key": value}
{"key": value}
.
.
.

Comment: Are we talking about one big JSON file or a file that contains JSON strings, one per line? What is the next step after parsing the JSON?

Comment: A file that contains JSON strings, one per line. The next step would be saving the result to S3, in the example I have mentioned, it would be 4 json files.

Comment: So what do you parse it for? Or you don't parse the JSON but just want to extract the strings as they are?

Comment: The parse will flatten the json, so I can latter use it to generate a parquet file out of it.

Comment: Your first problem is that you have a single gzip file. You could try `mgzip` module for parallel decompression. See https://github.com/vinlyx/mgzip
It might work better if the file was also compressed with mgzip. Your second problem is that parsing JSON into Python dicts is very slow, the creation of dict objects being the limiting factor. This is hard to overcome, especially not multithreaded, but maybe with multiprocessing. Btw. your example line is not valid JSON. Or are you saying each line is a single key-value-pair?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cut-and-dry basic skeleton of the functionality you're looking for:

```
import gzip
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor

def parse(line):
    print(f'Parsing: {line}')

with Executor(4) as e:
    with gzip.open('input.gz') as f:
        for line in f:
            e.submit(parse, line.decode())
```

The above code, as you specified, opens the gzip file and hands off, line-by-line, the complete content of the file to a pool of four processes.